# Spring Boot mandatory propagation for `Transactional` not working properly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

When there is a following call chain: rest method -> service1's transactional method (`propagation=Requires_New`) -> service2's transactional method (`propagation=Mandatory`):

```java
@Service
class Service1(
    private val service2: Service2
) {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    fun method1() {
        log.error("Transaction for method1: " + TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().transactionName)
        service2.method2()
    }
}


@Service
class Service2 {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    fun method2() {
        log.error("Transaction for method2: " + TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().transactionName)
    }
}
```

the log prints the following (the log is supposed to print the name of the current transaction for each method):

```
sb-repro     | 2024-02-20T13:20:25.000Z ERROR 1 --- [sb-repro] [   scheduling-1] c.r.s.persistence.service.Service1       : Transaction for method1: com.romankudryashov.sbrepro.persistence.service.Service1.method1
sb-repro     | 2024-02-20T13:20:25.000Z ERROR 1 --- [sb-repro] [   scheduling-1] c.r.s.persistence.service.Service2       : Transaction for method2: com.romankudryashov.sbrepro.persistence.service.Service2.method2
```

I think this is wrong (taking into account that `Mandatory` propagation should `Support a current transaction, throw an exception if none exists`) and the DB transaction for `method2` should be `com.romankudryashov.sbrepro.persistence.service.Service1.method1`.

Am I wrong or is that a bug?

Reproducer is here: https://github.com/rkudryashov/sb-repro. You just need to call `http://localhost:8080/test`

(build native image is not necessary to reproduce.)

Comment: spring's behaviour is correct, your expectations are wrong, yeap, `transaction` term is definitely confusing there. you may call `TransactionStatus#isNewTransaction` to check whether method has started new transaction or joined to already exisiting one.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32310#issuecomment-1959188856

just to get 30 symbols